# How do I find out more about "public beta"?

Tags: support

This is the only of the new round of SE sites that I'm involved in (quite possibly the only one I'm interested in) and my main experience of the SE/SO architecture comes from MO [mathoverflow] so I'm aware that there's a lot going on that I don't understand.  Is there somewhere that I can find out information about how it works (the setup, not the software) and details about stuff?

As an example of the sort of thing I'd like to know: someone remarked that everyone starts with reputation 101.  I definitely didn't; which is fine, but suggests that there are different "levels" of membership even in the private beta.  Are there people with more status than others?  (I don't mean in terms of numerical reputation, more important is the question as to whether there are people who the SE/SO team regard as "speaking for tex.SE.)

(I would like to make clear that I have no problem with their being a hierarchy of any sort, I just like to know if one exists (formally or informally) and know my place in it.)

Anyway, I guess that there's some central location where I can find out all this stuff and I'd find it useful to know where it resides.

Answer (score 2):

Mathoverflow is a stand-alone community. This site has been create as part of the area51 and stackexchange 2.0 "family". Hence this site has relationship with stackoverflow, superuser, serverfault, area51 and in the near future all the other beta websites.

If you read the [faq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq) for tex.se.com it mentions that if you have 200+ rep on the "siblings" websites you get a sign-up bonus rep. This is done to bootstrap the rep system and acknowledge previous contributors to other similar sites.